# Pick up a cache implementation, or roll your own?

Tags: java, caching

I'm doing a Java EE application, and I'm at a point where I've concluded that I need a cache for my objects.

My current requirements aren't much more complicated than some kind of key-value storage, possibly something that can handle a tree. It would be tempting to write a simple custom static/singleton class containing one or more maps. But, since there are several implementations that do more or less just like this (Memcached comes to mind), I began wondering that there must be some added value into using Memcached, instead of just my own implementation.

So, I'm asking for thoughts about this: why should I pick up a ready-made cache, when I can do my own static data? And vice versa; why should I write a static class, when I can pick up a ready-made cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For many cases of complex object graphs I had good-enough performance with a one-liner

```
new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap();
```

This creates a map using [Google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), with can be used as a cache for complex objects.

Since the keys are weak, and eventually go out of scope, it is unlikely that this will cause memory issues.

So I'd say for simple cases - don't bother with the "cognitive load" of a distributed cache. Serialisation issues, latency etc.. you will not want to handle those.

Comment: This MapMaker is something new to me. I must take a look at it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 9):

There are many cache implementations, both open source and commercial. There are many issues regarding writing a correct cache - time to leave of the objects, eviction policies, persistence, memory management, and more, so I wouldn't start one of my own (why to reinvent the wheel?)

Take a look at one of the following implementations:

- [EHCache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/)
- [OSCache](http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/)
- [JCS](http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs/)
- [JBossCache](http://labs.jboss.com/jbosscache/)
- [JCache](http://jcache.sourceforge.net/)

See more at http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions

Comment: So, assuming I have a one-VM application that can fit all the data I ever want in the cache at once, would you say that ready implementations have added benefits? Naturally, once there's more VMs, or I can't fit all the data at once in the cache, there's good reason to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: As with many things, it sounds like the implementers of existing cache libraries have just thought through a lot of the issues you will run into.  You should probably at least read the descriptions for each so that when a problem comes up in coding your cache you will readily recognize them and at least one potential solution.

Answer (score 3):

> "Why should I write a static class,
>   when I can pick up a ready-made
>   cache?"

When you don't want to include third-party dependencies in your project and there's no better way to learn how to write caches.